# add a foreign key constraint on a users primary address in rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "code_postal"
    t.string "street_name"
    t.string "street_number"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["code_postal"], name: "index_addresses_on_code_postal"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name_first"
    t.string "name_last"
    t.date "date_birth"
    t.string "address_email"
    t.integer "address_primary_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

A user can have many addresses, but a user can only have one primary address.

How do I add a foreign key constraint on address_primary_id?

Comment: You can add a foreign key in a migration, but I am not quite sure I did understand that correctly. How do you use the address_primary_id right now? Is there a relation set up in your model?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your associations look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address_primary, class_name: Address
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :user_as_primary, class_name: User, foreign_key: :address_primary_id
end
```

You can create a foreign key you want in a migration with this line:

```
add_foreign_key :users, :addresses, column: :address_primary_id
```

Here are the [docs on foreign keys in migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#foreign-keys).

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to add the column to the migration though `..., column: :address_primary_id` and have the relation be to the real table, or maybe pass the table name as well

Comment: @Ninigi You're right I do need to specify a column. Will edit.